# Ansible - Create a list with items and | list

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am trying to make a list inside a `uri` `body`. But using `|list` does not append the list items to the new list.

My task:

```
uri:
  url: "{{ URL }}"
  method: "POST"
  body:
    policies:
      - "default"
      - "{{ item | selectattr('policy', 'defined') | map(attribute='policy') | list }}"
    body_format: json
  with_items:
    - "{{ policy_config }}"
```

But this gives me:

```
policies:
  - \"default\"
  - \"[u'app1', u'app2']\"
```

So it is not appending the app1 & app2 as separate list items to the new one. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct single list. One of possible examples:

```
policies: "{{ ['default'] + item | selectattr('policy', 'defined') | map(attribute='policy') | list }}"
```

If `json_query` is available in your setup, even shorter:

```
policies: "{{ ['default'] + item | json_query('[].policy') }}"
```